# How to map an array of shape (4,386,258) to an array of shape (3, 386,258) in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm working in python and I have an image that is represented by the shape (4,386,258), I would like to represent it with the shape (3,386,258). Is there a way to do that? I don't know how to combine the information in order to get the right map

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your image is 386 pixels by 258 pixels and you have 4 channels, it means you want to convert the colour representation to one using only 3 channels, probably RGB. You haven't specified what libraries you used to read-in the image or where it is from, but most would have methods to handle this for you, so you don't have to write the conversion manually. They should also have methods of finding what the current colour representation is.